Get duplicate rows in a specific column from dataframe
I have a dataframe df:
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 3

data = [
    [10, 20, 30],
    [10, 50, 60],
    [70, 80, 90],
    [20, 30, 10],
    [20, 10, 20]
]

columns = [f"Column_{i+1}" for i in range(num_cols)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|
+--------+--------+--------+
|      10|      20|      30|
|      10|      50|      60|
|      70|      80|      90|
|      20|      30|      10|
|      20|      10|      20|
+--------+--------+--------+

I want to create another column with true/false based on the first column, where the first original value is "true", and any duplicate would be "fasle". So it would look like:
|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      10|      20|      30|    TRUE|
|      10|      50|      60|   FALSE|
|      70|      80|      90|    TRUE|
|      20|      30|      10|    TRUE|
|      20|      10|      20|   FALSE|


You did not specify how you determine the "original value" based on the first column, so I'm assuming it is okay to order by Column_2 and Column_3. Nevertheless, you can simply use a row_number() to determine the first row in a partition and populate the new values accordingly.
from pyspark.sql.window import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, when

df = df.withColumn(
    "Column_4",
    when(
        row_number().over(
            Window.partitionBy("Column_1").orderBy("Column_2", "Column_3")
        )
        == 1, 'TRUE'
    )
    .otherwise("FALSE"),
)
df.display()


just use Dataframe.duplicated can get the result
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def main():
    data = [
        [10, 20, 30],
        [10, 50, 60],
        [70, 80, 90],
        [20, 30, 10],
        [20, 10, 20]
    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data), columns=[f"column_{i}" for i in range(len(data[0]))])

    print(df)
    df["column_4"] = ~df['column_0'].duplicated()
    print(df)


which gives
   column_0  column_1  column_2
0        10        20        30
1        10        50        60
2        70        80        90
3        20        30        10
4        20        10        20
   column_0  column_1  column_2  column_4
0        10        20        30      True
1        10        50        60     False
2        70        80        90      True
3        20        30        10      True
4        20        10        20     False

